# Is this inequality true for integrals?

Tags: calculus, inequality

$$\left | \int_ {-a}^{0} f  - \int_{0}^{a} f \right | \geq  \left | \left | \int_ {-a}^{0} f \right |- \left | \int_{0}^{a} f \right| \right |  \geq \left | \int_ {-a}^{0} |f| -  \int_{0}^{a}| f |\right | $$

Can I apply the reverse and triangle inequalities like this? Assume $f$ is continuous everywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first inequality is true, the second often isn't.  Take $f$ to be $0$ on $[0,a]$, and defined on $[-a,0]$ in such a way that $\int_{-a}^0f=0$ but $\int_{-a}^0|f|>0$.

Comment: Huh? what do you mean?

Comment: I mean the second inequality is not generally true.  I mean that if $f:[-a,a]\to \mathbb R$ is any function of your choosing satisfying the properties that $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in[0,a]$, $\int_{-a}^0f(x)dx = 0$, and $\int_{-a}^0|f(x)|dx>0$, then the second inequality will be false for that $f$.  And implicitly I mean that you can come up with such an example without too much trouble.  $f$ will be sometimes positive, sometimes negative.  Actually any example where $f$ is $0$ on $[0,a]$ and changes signs on $[-a,0]$ will give a counterexample, but I wanted to point out a simple extreme case.

Comment: Oh okay, but there are cases when it applies right?

Comment: @sizz: Yes, for example when $f(x)=0$ for all $x$.  But it is not typical that it will hold.  Consider that it implies that $\int_{-a}^0|f(x)|dx\leq\left|\int_{-a}^0f(x)dx\right|$ when $f$ is zero on $[0,a]$, but this inequality is backwards.